# I'm trying to transact EOS using Scatter in eosjs version 20.0. I'm getting the "f not a function" error. Can someone please guide me?

Tags: eosjs, scatter

```
    const ScatterJS = require('scatterjs-core').default
const ScatterEOS = require('scatterjs-plugin-eosjs2').default
const Eos = require('eosjs')
const fetch = require('fetch'); //node only
const { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError } = require('eosjs');

//const api = new Api({ rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder() }); //required to submit transactions
ScatterJS.plugins(new ScatterEOS())


const network = ScatterJS.Network.fromJson({
    blockchain: 'eos',
    chainId: 'e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473',
    host: 'jungle2.cryptolions.io',
    port: 443,
    protocol: 'https'
});

//const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:443', { fetch });
const rpc = new JsonRpc(network.fullhost()); //required to read blockchain state

ScatterJS.connect('YourAppName', {network}).then(connected => {
    if(!connected) return console.error('no scatter');

    const eos = ScatterJS.eos(network, Api, {rpc});
   // let account = scatter.identity.accounts.find(x => x.blockchain === 'eos');
    ScatterJS.login().then(id => {
        if(!id) return console.error('no identity');
        const account = ScatterJS.account('eos');

        eos.transact({
            actions: [{
                account: 'eosio.token',
                name: 'transfer',
                authorization: [{
                    actor: account.name,
                    permission: account.authority,
                }],
                data: {
                    from: account.name,
                    to: 'bdtester1234',
                    quantity: '0.0001 EOS',
                    memo: account.name,
                },
            }]
        }, {
            blocksBehind: 3,
            expireSeconds: 30,
        }).then(res => {
            console.log('sent: ', res);
        }).catch(err => {
                console.log('\nCaught exception: ' + err);
                if (err instanceof RpcError)
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(err.json, null, 2));
            console.error('error: ', err);
        });
    });
});
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Caught exception: TypeError: f is not a function error:  { TypeError:
>   f is not a function
>       at JsonRpc. (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:99:46)
>       at step (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36:23)
>       at Object.next (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:17:53)
>       at E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:11:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:7:12)
>       at JsonRpc.fetch (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:92:16)
>       at JsonRpc. (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:208:55)
>       at step (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36:23) 
>   Blockquote
>
> Caught exception: TypeError: f is not a function error:  { TypeError:
>   f is not a function
>       at JsonRpc. (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:99:46)
>       at step (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36:23)
>       at Object.next (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:17:53)
>       at E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:11:71
>       at new Promise ()
>       at __awaiter (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:7:12)
>       at JsonRpc.fetch (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:92:16)
>       at JsonRpc. (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:208:55)
>       at step (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36:23)
>       at Object.next (E:\EOSIO\node_modules\eosjs\dist\eosjs-jsonrpc.js:17:53)
>   isFetchError: true }

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hi @AditiBobde You might check the eosjs compitable versions for scatter over https://github.com/GetScatter/scatter-js and configure your code as per the compitablity version of modules given in github.